# React-native-expo: Unhandled JS Exception: Unexpected identifier '_classCallCheck'. import call expects exactly one argument. no stack

Tags: react-native, expo

I am facing this error when i run

```
expo start
```

the project was running ok but when I stop sever and next day I open since then I am facing this error is there any solution.
the following is my `package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "7.1.3",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.4.4",
    "@react-native-community/hooks": "^2.8.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.8",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^5.0.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.3.5",
    "apisauce": "^1.1.1",
    "expo": "~44.0.0",
    "expo-constants": "^13.0.2",
    "expo-image-picker": "~12.0.1",
    "expo-location": "~14.0.1",
    "expo-permissions": "~13.1.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "formik": "^2.1.4",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.0.1",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.1.0",
    "react-native-progress": "^4.1.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.3.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.1.0",
    "@babel/core": "7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you checked [this post](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/32974) Gold tip: To avoid errors like this in the future, remove the "^" cases from versions.

Comment: Yes, I have done all these solutions not working for me.

Comment: any solutions on this?

Answer (score 0):

Luckilly I got the solution.

by updating babel-preset-expo

```
"babel-preset-expo": "~8.1.0",
```

to

```
"babel-preset-expo": "~8.3.0",
```

then run

```
expo start -c
```

Happy Coding!